# conversion from 12 hr to 24 hr in R and combine two tables

Tags: r, timestamp

The image for Y table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7svff.png)

I want to roll join two tables trial and trial2 with the key as time stamp. One table 'trial' has timestamp **POSIXct** as the key and other one 'trial2' has a timestamp in **character** . I tried to convert 'trial2' timestamo from 12 hour format to 24 hr format (POSIXct) so that I can apply roll join on them. But whatever I have used till now gave me NULL in the resulting field rolli for trial2.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
library(hms)
trial <- read_csv("X.csv")
trial2 <- read_csv("Y.csv")
trial2$rolli<- as.POSIXct(trial2$date ,format = '%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p')
#######OR#########
trial2$rolli<-strptime(trial2$date, "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p")
#######OR#########    
trial2$rolli<-ymd_hms(trial2$date)
trial<-mutate(trial, rolli=ymd_hms(paste("2018-11-27", Time), tz='Asia/Kolkata'))
trial<-data.table(trial)
trial2<-data.table(trial2)
setkey(trial, rolli)
setkey(trial2, rolli)
try<-trial[trial2, roll = "nearest"]

class(trial$rolli)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

class(trial2$rolli)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. Please click on the "r" below your question, then click on the "info" tab and take a look at the guidance on how to post a decent question.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging is always hard, so a general tip: try to reduce it as much as possible.

Looking at it, I'd think that the parsing of the character hits a problem. I'm not sure about lubridate and ymd_hms, but the as.POSIXct and strptime calls should work.
You can check by printing trial2$date and trial2$rolli. If the date looks fine, but rolli consists of all NA's, then that's the problem.

Probably the dates provided as characters are not in the exact right format, these functions can be very picky.
In order to know exactly what is going wrong, I'd need to see a sample of Y.csv, but you can check if you've typed everything exactly right: spaces, or have you switched "\" and "/"? Also, I normally work with 24-hour-notation, so it could be that strptime is picky about a specification being "am" or "AM" or "a.m." or something else.

EDIT: I've seen the format you're trying to supply, which has decimals in the seconds, which means %S doesn't do the trick.
Instead, you want %OS (it is in the help for ?strptime, but it's quite hidden). Also, I can't see it clearly in the image, but in your original code, there are 2 spaces between "%Y" and "%I". Are there 2 in your input as well?

Anyway:

```
strptime('11/27/2018 11:44:04.479 AM', format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%OS %p')
# Works with me
trial2$rolli<-strptime(trial2$date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%OS %p")
# Should solve your problem.
```

Furthermore, when *printing* trial2$rolli, the fractional part is not shown, but it *is* stored. You can show it with `as.numeric(trial2$rolli) %% 1`, although there may be some small rounding differences.

2nd EDIT:
To fix problems where you have times like 0:00 PM in your input (which is technically wrong, but you might not have control over your input), you can use:

```
trial2$date <- sub('0+(:..:..)', '12\1', trial2$date)
```

It replaces all occurences of the form 0 *:restoftime* or 00 *:restoftime* with 12 *:restoftime*
Only be careful about what your source actually means by something like 0:00:00.000 AM: is this midnight or noon? I don't know how R-functions handle this generally (or even if it's guaranteed to always be the same), and I'm not going to burn my hands on that question. If you look on the internet there are a lot of people who have very strong opinions on what AM/PM means in those circumstances, in all variations.

Comment: Thanks! Yes trial2$ rolli is NA.I will add an image of Y table.

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot. Works well but its turns out that rolli in trial2 is a list not a double so as.numeric changes the format of the date to 1540551858. Also when the time is 00.00 PM it does not show 12 : 00. It shows NA values there.

Comment: Well, when printing the while number, it also rounds to a set number of decimals. Try `as.numeric(trial2$rolli)-1540551850`, it should show 8. _something_ (in the example that gives 1540551858).
As for 0:00 PM (or AM): technically, that's an error in your input, it should read 12:00 PM (or AM). But I've edited my answer as to how you can fix it.